# Getting the full git log after rolling back to a previous version

Tags: windows, git

I'm new to git, and probably not using correct terminology, so bear with me :)

Let's say I have a repository with 5 changes, e.g.

```
D:\test\gitrepo2>git log --oneline
3a5fd33 555
3cfbfae 444
e9a78c8 333
a618586 222
b80d5e1 111
```

I learned that I can sync back to an earlier revision by doing:

```
D:\test\gitrepo2>git reset e9a78c8 --hard
HEAD is now at e9a78c8 333
```

**My question is: after doing this, how can I get the full log, so that I can go back to the most recent revision?**

Running log no longer shows those revisions:

```
D:\test\gitrepo2>git log --oneline
e9a78c8 333
a618586 222
b80d5e1 111
```

I also tried add the --all switch, which didn't make a difference. In Mercurial, under the same scenario, running 'hg log' gives the complete log even after I update to an earlier revision.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume by "sync back" you really mean you just want your working copy to look like a previous point in time. To do that, you want `checkout`, not `reset`:

```
> git checkout e9a78c8
```

At that point, your repository looks like this:

```
> git log master --oneline
3a5fd33 555   <--- master is still here
3cfbfae 444
e9a78c8 333   <--- HEAD (working copy) is here
a618586 222
b80d5e1 111
```

Now to get back to the latest commit on `master`, just `git checkout master` again.

By using `reset`, you got this instead:

```
> git log master --oneline
e9a78c8 333   <--- HEAD (working copy) and master are here
a618586 222
b80d5e1 111
```

Comment: Yep, I was indeed getting confused between checkout and reset. checkout does seem to do what I want, and is clearly the closer equivalent to 'hg update hash'.

Answer (score 10):

Using `git reset` updates the pointer (refs/heads/master) to point to an earlier revision. It doesn't actually make a new revision that effectively rolls back to that earlier revision, which I assume is what your "Mercurial equivalent" does (and this is somewhat like what `git revert` does).

Git does, however, keep a log file of how refs/heads/master has changed over time, and a separate one for HEAD. You can view this in fairly raw form using

```
git reflog show HEAD
```

(or master) or in a more familiar form by simply using

```
git log -g
```

This mode of git log shows reflog entries rather than walking through the revision graph: `git log -g -n 10` will show the last 10 things that HEAD pointed to- so it would be the same as `git log -n 10` if all you had done was plain `git commit`s.

However, it will also show changing branches, resetting etc.

```
git log -g master
```

will show only reflog entries where the master branch changed (changing branches doesn't appear in any branch reflog at all).

Comment: To clarify, I'm not trying to create a new revision that rolls back the changes, but only to move the pointer back in time (this is what 'hg update' does). So in that sense, 'git reset' does what I want. I just tried 'git log -g' as well, but it gives a long list of things that are non-trivial to correlate to what the full log is.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to go back, consider doing a (headless) checkout instead (`git checkout HEAD^`)

---

I think you simply needed

```
git log HEAD@{1}
```

So, e.g. on a fresh repo

```
mkdir -pv /tmp/repo
cd /tmp/repo
git init
touch a 
git add .
git commit -am 1
echo something > a
git commit -am 2
git reset --hard HEAD^
git log HEAD@{1}
```

Output:

```
commit ca6f2c6c1b07895816a1b75973035a20a0238607
Author: Seth <sehe@xxxxxxxxx>
Date:   Thu Apr 21 01:17:06 2011 +0200

    2

commit d71ea3dfa89771af6d3ae2d0e88e1dc6ccce48b8
Author: Seth <sehe@xxxxxxxxx>
Date:   Thu Apr 21 01:16:56 2011 +0200

    1
```

Comment: I think you're right that 'git checkout' may in fact be what I was after instead of 'git reset'. I'm having trouble with the HEAD^ syntax, though. When I run 'git checkout HEAD^', it prompts me with 'More?' and I'm not clear what it's after.

Comment: Try quoting it like `'HEAD^'` or use the alternative spellings `'HEAD~1'` or even `'HEAD~'`. `man git-rev-parse` will help you get the full picture

Comment: Double quoting it worked: "HEAD^". Might be a Windows command line thing.

Comment: Dang... it would have helped to tag it windows. As it happens, I didn't see it implicitly :)

Comment: Just did it now. I know, a little late :)