# How to cancel checkout in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, git

I have these commits on my project:

- Commit 1
- Commit 2
- Commit 3
- Commit 4
- Commit 5

I wanted to see something in Commit 3, so on source control I choosed "Checkout" on Commit 3. It revert to Commit 3.

But now in the list of commits I can't see Commit 4 and Commit 5 anymore!
Does it mean I lost all my work?
Is it really so simple to lose everything?

Comment: what platform are you using to make VersionControl? Bitbucket? Github?

Comment: Local Version control included in xCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you did not lose all your work. No it is not that simple. Once you commit something, it should be very easy to recover it.

You can always go to your Version Control platform, look the commit history on a branch, pick a commit ID and revert to it.

You can try: `git reflog` and get the ID.

Then you can checkout to that ID, check on how to do it on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777222/8869493

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the last item in the history is "commit 3". The filter is on "All items". Could it be because I only have a local repository ?

Comment: What do you see when you `git log` on terminal, at your project folder?

Comment: Same: all commits until Commit 3

Comment: Try: `git log --all`

Comment: Same: all commits until Commit 3 :(

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737579/getting-the-full-git-log-after-rolling-back-to-a-previous-version

Comment: Looked at it. Made 'git checkout master' to revert to my previous Commit 5, and now I got back to the very first commit, three months ago ! All commits disappeared, can't believe it !

Comment: Also check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427288/how-to-get-back-to-the-latest-commit-after-checking-out-a-previous-commit/2427389

Comment: Don't panic, every commit can be recovered.

Comment: Also, this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099258/how-can-i-recover-a-lost-commit-in-git

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Read and tried everything from various posts. Downloaded Github desktop to have better view, history is empty now, got back to my very first commit. Seems that making checkout from xCode reverts back and delete most recent work... Just have to kill myself!

Comment: what do you see when you `git reflog`?

Comment: Can't see the commit Id in xCode neither in Github desktop, but found it directly in file `.git/logs/HEAD` under project account. Then applied `git reset HEAD --hard <commit_id>` and alleluia went back to last commit! Thanks for your help and patience.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is see something in Commit 3, double-click Commit 3 in the list of commits. Xcode's editor will show you a list of all the files you modified in that commit. Select a file to see the changes you made to that file.

Checking out commits is a bad idea. When you check out a commit, you end up with a detached head, which means the repository has no current branch. With no current branch, you are going to run into problems committing to the repository. A better alternative to checking out a commit is to create a branch off that commit.

To get back to Commit 5, check out the branch that has Commit 5.